# Get current Locale in Entity Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I spent Hours for searching how can I get the current Locale in Entity but with any result.
Can Some one tell how can I do it ?
Thanks

Comment: If you're looking for Symfony's Locale, you cannot retrieve it from an Entity.  Could you explain more what you are looking to do?  It will probably end up being a candidate for a Symfony service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Symfony, locale is stored in the `request` object. (see [Handling the User's Locale](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#handling-the-user-s-locale)). Entities, by themselves, are not aware of the current locale (and should not be; that's how they're designed - they're simple classes that hold data; they should not be aware of the environment parameters). If you want to make them aware of the current locale you will have to create a [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html), that will handle the business logic between the two separate domains (Entity and Request).